# Какой корень в слове чудесный?

Tags: словообразование

Какой корень в слове чудесный?

Answer (score 1):

Корень чуд, образовано от слова "чудо".
а разбор на морфемы такой: чуд-ес-н-ый

Answer (score 1):

Чуд/о - чуд/ес/а - чуд/ес/н/ый, корень ЧУД.

ЕС - формообразующий суффикс, выделяется  формах мн. числа некоторых существительных: небо - небеса, чудо - чудеса.

**Обновление**

Казалось бы, простой вопрос, но здесь  возможны два ответа: корень ЧУД- и корень ЧУДЕС- (что можно видеть из ответов на различных форумах). Дело в том, что ЕС - суффикс формообразующий, а не словообразующий, отсюда и варианты. Дополнительная информация в моем ответе "низкого", с Вашей точки зрения,  качества  снимает  эти разногласия и соответствует "Толковому словарю словообразовательных частиц" под ред. Ефремовой. Могу порекомендовать Вам иногда туда заглядывать.

Comment: Исправил ответ.